# How do I brush chart nodes in a D3 SVG?

Tags: charts, d3.js, selection

In D3, we have [brush](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush) mechanism on one axis of a plot.

Now I have a scatterplot in an SVG where each node stands for a user. I want to brush on this SVG to select adjacent users. How could I build such a "brush" operation?

Comment: The brush isn't specific to axes. You can apply it to anything and also select two-dimensional regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want a 2D [brush component](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#brush)?

[image]

[Here's a good example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663), as pictured above. The take-home part:

```
var brush = d3.svg.brush()
  .x(x)
  .y(y)
  .on("brushstart", brushstart)
  .on("brush", brushmove)
  .on("brushend", brushend);
```

Calling the `x` and `y` setters on a brush component with your horizontal and vertical [scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Scales) makes it resizeable in both dimensions.

As usual, you can [call the brush component](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Controls#wiki-_brush) to render it into an element:

```
cell.call(brush);
```